# C# error C0115: GetComponent<Rigedbody2D>

Tags: c#, youtube, unity-game-engine

I have only an average knowledge on JAVA and recently i wanted to try out unity. So with a YT tutorial(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V7YhzzfiW9c) and some good hopes i started, Unity uses C# so it went all right to follow. But it seemed the guy on the video was using unity 4 or something, and since then has the command: RigedBody2D.something.something; changed into GetComponent(something);. So when i changed it i got the CS0115 error.

Here is the code i used:

```html
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class Player : Entity {

    void Start () {
 
 }
 
 void Update () {

        if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Z)) || (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))) {

            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(transform.position += Vector3.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        }

        if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) || (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))) {

            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(transform.position += Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        }

        if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) || (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))) {

            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(transform.position += Vector3.down * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        }

        if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q)) || (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))) {

            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(transform.position += Vector3.left * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        }
    }
}
```

And this is the error message:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1501  No overload for method 'GetComponent' takes 1 arguments KnightRPG.CSharp    C:\Users\beheerder\Documents\KnightRPG\Assets\Code\Entities\Player\Player.cs    14  Active

I don't know why this is happening but i would apriciate it if you could help me! Tank you!

-SV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says, the method `GetComponent<T>` takes no arguments. It only returns a reference to an instance of type T (where T in your case stands for Rigidbody2D). And you also try to pass an assignment as argument to said function, that wont work either, you can only pass values or references.

You should have posted a timestamp to where in the video the guy does that, but i found it on the first click :D

So, what he writes translates to

`GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().transform.position += Vector3.up * speed * Time.deltaTime;`

in Unity5.